# UIview clear a zone

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, ios6, iphone-5, ios4

This is an inherited code, I would like to change as few as possible, just give support for iphone5 (taler) screen size.

Somewhere I have a code like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:leftSwipedViewController.view];
```

The problem is: the parent UIViewController has filled out the 480x2 -> 568x2 zone ( difference between iphone4 and iphone5) the new swiped UIController will fill the 0->480x2 height zone. I would like to clear the remain space with a nice white color. How to do it?

something like `[self.view  clearRectangle(0,568-480,320,568, color.white)];` but this function doesn't exist as is.

Is there any better, fast solution? - I don't want to create a xib file for a code where the component are place from within code to X, Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very simple actually

Right before adding your view, do this:

```
UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
whiteView.tag = 123; // you'll need it if you want to remove it later.
whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:whiteView];

[self.view addSubview:leftSwipedViewController.view];
```

When you want to remove it, do this:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:123] removeFromSuperview];
```

However, the correct approach would be to make your leftSwipedViewController support both heights